# using a for loop to print using paste() function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, cross-validation

I wrote a custom function to divide a data frame into k folds for k-fold cross-validation and want to print out the start and end indices of the folds to check if the division was done correctly. I'm using the `paste()` function within a `for` loop. When I run the function, I get no error but nothing gets printed. When I copy just the `paste()` line into the terminal it prints the last index correctly, which suggests that the function was executed correctly. So why it is not printing the `paste()` line from within the function? I would be grateful for any advice on this.

```
fold_index_counter = function(k, data){

  n = nrow(data)

  for (i in 1:k){
    start = (n*i)/k
    end = (n*(i+1))/k-1
    paste("Fold no. ", i, " starts at row ", start, " and ends at row ", end, sep = "")
  }  
}

fold_index_counter(10, dat.cor.trim)
```

Comment: Within a loop use a `print()`, `cat()` or even a `message()` function. Edit: there is a bigger problem, you want to print inside a function, which as well demans a "printing" function.

Comment: And if you want to print something immediately without waiting for the whole loop to end (as in your situation) `cat()` and `flush.console()` might be needed.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.